# How do I test throughput/packet-loss an ethernet switch and it's associated cabling?

Tags: ethernet, iperf

I'm trying to figure out the test setup for this. Currently, I have two PC's on the same switch.

I was able to setup Ostinato on both machines and have the "Ostinato" GUI connect to the drone. But the testing seem to be limited with ethernet port to the local loopback.

I'm open to using other performance tools as well, like iperf. Also, platform is irrelevant, I can do windows or linux.

Comment: I'd be *very* surprised Ostinato is limited to the loopback! Do you run it as root (sudo)? Most if not all traffic generation/collection tools require CAP_NET_ADMIN privilege to run at some level on real interfaces. The same would go for iperf: sudo iperf blablabla.

Comment: It isn't but I'm not sure how to set it up to have the packets go between the two PC's

Comment: Then it's an Ostinato problem. 1/ Read the doc. 2/ If still not OK got to the Ostinato people [searching their mailing list archive](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ostinato), 3/ if still not OK join the list [here](http://ostinato.org/#mailing-list) and ask. As for iperf you'll find tons of test examples/tutorials just googling.

Answer (score 0):

Same question was asked on the Ostinato mailing list and answered there -

> You don't need 2 PCs. You can use one PC with 2 ports.
>
> Connect the 2 ports on your PC e.g. eth0 and eth1 to DUT ports X and Y 
>   respectively. Configure the DUT to forward packets received on port X 
>   to port Y. Using the Ostinato GUI configure a stream on eth0. Click 
>   Apply, select eth0 in the stats window and click Transmit.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ostinato/zGMjADgDPII